# CodeIgniter - Class 'CI_Loader' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to extend `CI_Loader` class to override `_ci_load_library()`, but I'm receiving:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Loader' not found in C:\Users\X\workspace\ci-app\application\core\MY_Loader.php on line 4
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Class 'CI_Loader' not found

Filename: core/MY_Loader.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:
```

The class `MY_Loader` is located in `application/core/MY_Loader.php`, and it's like this:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _ci_load_library($class, $params = NULL, $object_name = NULL)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm using the latest version of CodeIgniter: **3.1.9**

Comment: Same version of CI, made a file called `MY_Loader` with the same contents as yours... no issues.

Comment: can you check if you have class file in ROOT/system/core/Loader.php ?

Comment: @LeenaPatel yes, I have this class file

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding below line above declaration of class MY_Loader

```
 require APPPATH."../system/core/Loader.php";
```

Comment: It works with this require, but by the CodeIgniter documentation the class CI_Loader initializes automatically by the system. If I use the require instead of fix the problem, maybe there is another core class that is not loading also. So the question is: What are the reasons that are making this class not initializes?

Comment: May be there is some configuration in system/core/Config.php missing in your case. can you post code from your system/core/Config.php in your question

Comment: Check if `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_'`  in `application/config/config.php`

Comment: here is my configuration file: https://gist.github.com/thiagobit/c0498a6f3f25454df25003474f87c077

Comment: In my case `$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;` and `$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();` . But i am not sure that it is causing issue. you can try changing it..

Comment: Nevermind. As I imported some files from other project I excluded all those files and the MY_Loader is working now. I think it was a namespace problem. But thanks for the help!